# Standard Deviation and Median Takes Long to Load on Big File

Tags: java, arrays, list, math, println

I'm running into an issue where both my standard dev. and my median are taking too long to get printed but everything else prints quickly. This only occurs when I have a larger list, I am not understanding the problem, as the numbers are not too large it should fit into both double or integer form, its just not getting displayed at a buttons click like the other values.

**Current Code**

```
package Labs;

import java.util.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
/**
 *
 * @author nick a
 */
public class Practice {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    private static final DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Double[] dataArray = {16500.0, 304000.0, 384500.0, 431500.0, 681500.0, 348500.0, 282500.0, 327000.0, 182500.0};
        List<Double> data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(dataArray));
        System.out.println("StDev Value from list: " + df.format(stdev(data)));
        System.out.println("Median Value from list: " + df.format(median(data)));
        
    }
    public static double stdev(List<Double>values){
        double sumOfDiff = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++){
            sumOfDiff += Math.pow(Math.abs(values.get(i)) - mean(values), 2);   
        }
        double resultant = sumOfDiff/values.size();
        return Math.sqrt(resultant);
    }
    public static double median(List<Double>values){
        List<Double>sorted = new ArrayList<>(values);
        Collections.sort(sorted);
        if(sorted.size() % 2 == 0){
            int evenMid = sorted.size()/2;
            double sumEven = sorted.get(evenMid-1) + sorted.get(evenMid);
            return sumEven/2; 
        }
        int oddMid = (sorted.size()+1)/2;
        return sorted.get(oddMid-1);
    }
}
```

The problem happens when the list becomes super large (400,000) entries... I have other things printed out like mean, range, min, max etc. but as soon as its time for standard deviation and median to be printed out it takes its sweet time unlike the rest. How might I fix this?

Comment: In `stdev()`, rewrite it so `mean(values)` is only called once and I bet it'll run faster. In `median()`, I imagine most of the time is spent in first copying the argument and sorting the copy. Can you just sort the original values list? Does anything else it's passed to depend on a particular order?

Comment: Hi @Shawn No nothing depends on a particular order i made the functions myself! I will try and change it and see if it performs faster, thankyou!

Comment: Setting the mean(values) function equal to a variable decreased the run time, so thankyou @Shawn it also fixed the median response as i think it was just waiting for standard deviations output.